# Dual monitors and command line

Tags: command-line, multiple-monitors

I set up Gnome to use 2 monitors in extended mode - and it works great as expected. Now I'm wondering wether it is possible to use this setup in the console mode.

Currently I see the same command line window on both monitors (Clone view)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not possible, I'm reasonably sure.

But you can, as a workaround, use Gnome-Terminal. Press <kbd>F11</kbd> to get the terminal into full screen mode. As soon as you hit any key, the mouse cursor disappears, giving you the full old-school feeling. :-)

Related question (Unanswered) on the Unix Stackexchange: [TTY On External Monitor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5012/tty-on-external-monitor)

Comment: Actually, I want this kind of environment.
I hope in my Extended monitor I can run a TTY console, while in my primary, I'll run xserver.